# Making an http request from react app with API running on localhost

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, express, axios

On my main PC I have a react app running `http://localhost:3000`, aswell as a nodejs and express API `http://localhost:3001`, so my react app requests the data from the API that is running on the same machine and it works fine, it loads up the web app and succesfully makes the http requests. I now want to visit the react app from a different computer, so when I vist my react app, using my main computers internal IP, the react app loads up perfectly fine, but the API request fails. In console I get `GET http://localhost:3001/today net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, when making my axios request I dont refer to the API as `http://localhost:3001` I use the public IP of my computer instead of localhost, I also have went into my router and forwarded ports 3000 and 3001. So it looks to me like even when I'm on a different computer, the react app still thinks it is on localhost. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I port forwarded ports 3000 and 3001, I forgot to change the protocols from tcp to tcp/udp. It works fine when I use both TCP and UDP to port forward

Answer (score 2):

I think you are going CORS (cross-origin resource sharing ) issue. I mean you have this error because your server (NodeJS) an your App(React) are running on the same computer. So you need to enable CORS :

1. open your package.json file and add this property :
   **"proxy":"http://localhost:3001"**
   2)In your React App instead of making your requests to **fetch("http://localhost:3001/users")** you'll send your requests like this **fetch("/users")**

[Click here to read more](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/react-cors-guide-what-it-is-and-how-to-enable-it/)